# Getting error on Module submission on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, package

I have submitted my module in magento 2 marketplace. My module got rejected on technical review and shown below error:

> Environment: Operating System - Centos 7, PHP Version - 5.6.30, Magento Platform - 2.1.5 CE

Command: composer require propellents/testimonials:1.0.0'
Installation issue: Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for magento/magento2ce 2.1.5 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2ce[2.1.5].
- propellents/testimonials 1.0.0 requires magento/framework ~100.0.4 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.0.12, 100.0.13, 100.0.14, 100.0.15].
- don't install magento/framework 100.0.4|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.5
- don't install magento/framework 100.0.5|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.5
- don't install magento/framework 100.0.6|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.5
- don't install magento/framework 100.0.7|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.5
- don't install magento/framework 100.0.8|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.5
- don't install magento/framework 100.0.9|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.5
- don't install magento/framework 100.0.10|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.5
- don't install magento/framework 100.0.11|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.5
- don't install magento/framework 100.0.12|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.5
- don't install magento/framework 100.0.13|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.5
- don't install magento/framework 100.0.14|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.5
- don't install magento/framework 100.0.15|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.5
- Installation request for propellents/testimonials 1.0.0 -> satisfiable by propellents/testimonials[1.0.0].


    Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] sh
    [DockerOperationsPHP56Magento21CE] Running shell script
    + echo Failure
    Failure
```

After solving above error now I am getting below error.

```
Environment: Operating System - Centos 7, PHP Version - 7.0.15, Magento Platform - 2.0.13 CE

Command: deploy:mode:set production
Installation issue: Enabled maintenance mode
Static content deployment start
Requested languages: en_US
Requested areas: adminhtml, frontend
Requested themes: Magento/backend, Magento/blank, Magento/luma
=== adminhtml -> Magento/backend -> en_US ===
=== frontend -> Magento/blank -> en_US ===
=== frontend -> Magento/luma -> en_US ===
......................................................................................................................................................
Successful: 2054 files; errors: 0
---

..
Successful: 1981 files; errors: 0
---


Successful: 1849 files; errors: 0
---

=== Minify templates ===

Successful: 854 files modified
---

New version of deployed files: 1492507317
Static content deployment complete
Start compilation
Command returned non-zero exit code:
`php -f /var/www/html/bin/magento setup:di:compile-multi-tenant 2>&1`
+ '[' ']'
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (indexer:reindex)
[Pipeline] sh
```

Anyone who can help. I have prepared my module and about to publish it. But not able to rectify this issue. Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Please first accept answers in your previous questions to help the community

Comment: Your answer didn't help me.

Comment: I am not talking about only my answer :), I can see 2-3 more questions in your profile and which are unaccepted

Comment: It may be the same reason @KeyurShah otherwise I always accept if it is usefull for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the unwanted module's references in composer.json require block.

```
"require": {
        "php": "~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6"
}
```

Just keep the PHP version dependency or provide the latest version of the dependency module.

For this module, instead of magento/framework ~100.0.4, try magento/framework ~100.1.* which ensures your module depends on latest version of magento framework module.

Comment: I have removed that and it removed my previous error. But now it is showing different error. Please check it on my question

Comment: I guess this is because of compilation errors. Try running bin/magento setup:di:compile and look for any duplicate dependency errors. Once you fixed that, this will be solved